# display image with html and php

Tags: php, html

I know how to add a description like this one:

```
$h .= '<a href="#">'.mysql_result($res,$z,"name").'</a>';
```

But how can I add a image to display?
I'm always starting with ($h .=) and I need MySQL_result

```
 <img class="img-responsive" src="/IMAGES_HOTELS/burj_al_arab_1.jpg" alt="">';
```

Can someone transform the code. Starting with $h .= '

I tried this code but it doesn't work (the URL is the src of my image from db

```
$h.= mysql_result($res,$z,"URL");
```

Comment: can you tell what you are seeking exact output?

Comment: when I add  <img class="img-responsive" src="/IMAGES_HOTELS/burj_al_arab_1.jpg" alt="">'; I get a picture but I don't want the link it needs a MySQL_result

Comment: Did you try this $h.= '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.mysql_result($res,$z,"URL").'" alt="">';

Comment: How about just dropping the concatenation then and simply using `$h`? You are concatenating a link and then an image...

Comment: I know how to add a description from MySQL on my website. but I cant get the images to show

Comment: actually this what will give output? mysql_result($res,$z,"URL")

Comment: yes mysql_result($res,$z,"URL") but not the image